# originality.ai API request, {"error":"invalid api call"}", where's the issue?

Tags: php, api, curl

```
function originlaity_ai()
{

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.originality.ai/api/v1//scan/ai');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{\"content\": \"A delicious cup of tea is a simple and timeless pleasure, and for many people its even more than that...\"}');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'X-OAI-API-KEY: XXXXXXXXXXX';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    var_dump($result);
    curl_close($ch);
}

originlaity_ai();
```

the doc says
Making Requests

1. In order to use our API you'll need to create an API key on the "My Keys" table on the left or click this button:
2. To start making requests: Create a header key named X-OAI-API-KEY and use your api key as the value in your application of choice
3. Main Endpoint:
   https://api.originality.ai/api/v1
4. All Request responses are returned in JSON

AI Detection
[POST]
/scan/ai

Run an AI Detection scan for a full piece of content

Request Example:

{
"content": "A delicious cup of tea is a simple and timeless pleasure, and for many people it's even more than that..."
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://api.originality.ai/api/v1/scan/ai";
$headerKey = "xxxx";
$data = array (
        "title" => "test title",
        "content" => "A delicious cup of tea is a simple and timeless pleasure, and for many people its even more than that"
);
$jsonData = json_encode ( $data );



$ch = curl_init ( $url );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-OAI-API-KEY:' . $headerKey
) );

$response = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

echo $response;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).